# Infer to a narrow string literal type from return type

Tags: typescript

```
const createFruit = <T extends string[]>(fruits: T): typeof fruits[0] => fruits[0]

const fruit = createFruit(['apple', 'orange']) // fruit is of type `string`
```

I want the type of `fruit` to be inferred to the string literal `apple`. Is there no way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the [variadic tuple](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/39094) syntax for the `fruits` parameter will hint to the compiler to infer the literal type.

```
const createFruit = <T extends string[]>(
  fruits: [...T]
): typeof fruits[0] => fruits[0]

const fruit = createFruit(['apple', 'orange'])
//    ^? fruit: "apple"
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBMBOBTAhlRAxeBXAlrAvDADwAqMiAHmmACYQzTw5gDmA2gLoB8AFAGbY8EAFww2AOkkkOASlFQAngAdEIPjAG4oENgAYOMfFw2DtejgCgLoSLE15DcJKgymebAOTIlSgDaIPABoYDxB4ZFYA2SA)

Comment: silly (related) example, do you know why this errors: `const createFruit = <T extends string[]>(fruits: T): typeof fruits extends [infer x,...infer _] ? typeof fruits[0] : typeof fruits[0] => fruits[0];`?

Comment: `typeof fruits` resolves to the generic type `T`. The compiler does not try to reason about conditional types whenever they depend on a generic type. Even if both branches resolve to the same result.

Comment: @TobiasS. Just a minor point: the compiler doesn't always infer the literals inside the tuple, it depends on the upper bound you choose.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBMBOBTAhlRAxeBXAlrAvDADwAqMiAHmmACYQxZgDWYIA7mANoC6AfABQAzbHggAuGJwB0MktwCUEqAE8ADohCCYw3FAicADNxj5e2kXsPcAUNdCRYOvCbhJUGC-04ByZKtUANojeADQw3iDwyGAA5sEKQA

Comment: @TobiasS. Thanks, do you know where I can read more about that behavior?

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava - The PR I linked in my answer covers the inference of tuples. *"When the contextual type of an array literal is a tuple type, a tuple type is inferred for the array literal*". Details about why adding `string` to the constraint infers the literal types can be found at [this PR](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/10676). *"T is widened to its widened literal type if ... T has no constraint or its constraint does not include primitive or literal types"*

Comment: @TobiasS. No I was referring to further info about the comment which you wrote to me: " The compiler does not try to reason about conditional types whenever they depend on a generic type."

Comment: you can find similar issues here: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43846 or  https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28884. They talk about situations where results of utlility types like `Pick` or `Exclude` cant be assigned to when given a generic type. It boils down to the same issue since they are implemented using conditional types.

Comment: @TobiasS. Thanks I'll have a look. With TS sometimes you have to look for explanation on github, instead of docs, which is a bit inconvenient

Comment: Thank you! Solid answer.

Answer (score 2):

From TS `5.0` you will be able to use the [`const` modifier on type parameters](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/51865) like this:

```
const createFruit = <const T extends readonly string[]>(fruits: T): T[0] => fruits[0]

const fruit = createFruit(['apple', 'orange'])
```

For now a possible solution is the following:

```
const createFruit = <N extends string, T extends N[] | []>(fruits: T): T[0] => fruits[0]

const fruit = createFruit(['apple', 'orange'])
```

In which you declare another type parameter `N` to narrow the inference from strings to actual string type literals, then you set the upper-bound for `T` to `T[] | []`, where the `| []` tells TS to infer a tuple type instead of an array tipe.

In both cases the return type could simply be `T[0]`.

Comment: Strange hack, didn't know that

Answer (score 2):

In order to get stronger typings that would give the desired behavior, just type the argument as immutable array, and then use the [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) to type the value you pass as argument:

```
const createFruit = <T extends readonly string[]>(fruits: T): typeof fruits[0] => fruits[0]

const fruit = createFruit(['apple', 'orange'] as const) // fruit is of type `apple`
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/MYewdgzgLgBMBOBTAhlRAxeBXAlrAvDADwAqMiAHmmACYQxLI3gA2AnjNPDmAOYDaAXQB8ACgBm2PBABcMEgEo5UNgAdEIcTEm4oEfgAZBMfMO1S9hwQChroSLB14TcRmky7R-AOTJVqlkRvABoYbxB4ZD4g42R6e2gFGAB6ZPNdGBx6TRgVdRgAAz8AxAKgA)

Comment: Thanks - another solid solution